# Bard Muse Spell Heightening

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

Each [muse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Muses.aspx) that a bard chooses adds a spell to their spell repertoire. I'm particularly interested in the [soothe](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=291) spell that comes with the [maestro muse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Muses.aspx?ID=2).

But I was wondering if/how these muse spells are heightened. As written, they are added to the bard's spell repertoire. At level one, they are obviously level 1 spells. But for spells that can be heightened, such as soothe, are these automatically heightened at all or are they always there in the bards spell repertoire as a level 1 spell?

My hunch is that they are not automatically heightened (as if a cantrip or focus spell) and if a bard wants a level 2 soothe, they will need to use one of their standard spell repertoire slots.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### It's Not Automatically Heightened

Each [Muse](https://2e.aonprd.com/Muses.aspx) grants you one spell known in your repertoire, but there's no mention that you get it at every spell level. As such you would only know the spell as its base form, as a 1st-level spell.

You could choose to learn this spell at higher levels as you level up naturally, or you could designate the spell as one of your [Signature Spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Classes.aspx?ID=3) which allow for free heightening.

> Experience allows you to cast some spells more flexibly. For each spell level you have access to, choose one spell of that level to be a signature spell. You don’t need to learn heightened versions of signature spells separately; instead, you can heighten these spells freely.

Comment: Ah, okay! I didn't realize it was eligible to be a signature spell. That's great to know.

Comment: @AustinBrown If this answered your question,  click the arrow next to it to mark it as accepted (Which also grants some rep)